# NPM INSTALL generates error when performing npm install or npm install for any module

Tags: node.js, npm-install

This is my ERROR

```
13 silly saveTree `-- zone.js@0.8.26  <-- LAST GOOD INSTALL OF A MODULE
14 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 258612
14 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
14 verbose stack     at module.exports (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\parse-json.js:3:15)
14 verbose stack     at BB.join (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\install\read-shrinkwrap.js:31:20)
14 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
14 verbose stack     at Holder$3._callFunction (eval at generateHolderClass (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\join.js:92:16), <anonymous>:14:44)
14 verbose stack     at Holder$3.checkFulfillment (eval at generateHolderClass (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\join.js:92:16), <anonymous>:29:30)
14 verbose stack     at Promise.eval (eval at thenCallback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\join.js:14:16), <anonymous>:6:20)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:566:21)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._fulfill (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:638:18)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:582:21)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
14 verbose stack     at Promise._fulfill (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:638:18)
14 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\nodeback.js:42:21
15 verbose cwd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\repos\forms-ui
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
18 verbose node v8.11.1
19 verbose npm  v5.6.0
20 error Unexpected token < in JSON at position 258612
21 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I don't understand why this is happening all of a sudden.

STEPS I TOOK:

1. I dump node-modules folders
2. I did a hard reset on origin/develop to go back to a good install
3. I noticed that my JSON object un-formatted itself to STRAIGHT lines on save
4. Issues npm install or npm install  --save and get this error for anything:

   $ npm install
   npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 258612

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     C:\Users\pborreggine\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-08-09T17_40_28_820Z-debug.log

Has anyone ever seen or experienced this before?

UPDATE:

One of the recommendations I got is found in this github thread is to remove the package.lock file and try again. There are a couple of other suggestions in this SO thread.

I did that but now my package.json is out of format and now I'm getting this error:

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! file C:\inetpub\wwwroot\repos\myproject\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected string in JSON at position 2121 while parsing '{
npm ERR!   "name": "forms-ui", "version": "2.0'
npm ERR! File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\repos\myproject\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

The package JSON is ALL STRAIGHT LINES now and when I try to REFORMAT into JSON, on save, in NETBEANS 8.2, it REFUSES to keep it.

Sorry for the all caps. It's for emphasis.

Comment: Issue seems to be clearly yelling of malformed json `Unexpected token < in JSON`, throw it in https://jsonlint.com/ and report back?

Comment: It's not and it is...  here's the problem:  https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=269417 - It's NETBEANS' fault.

Comment: Using netbeans for writing node apps is probably not going to yield you the best experience. Why not check out vscode or atom?

Comment: I've been using Netbeans since 2013. VSCode actually REMOVES empty tags that I've use for populating at run time and it messes up the code. I'll check out ATOM and there's Angular Studio now... an IDE for Angular, pretty cool.